# Creating choropleth map using basemap and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to create a choropleth map using basemap and pandas, to plot the level of prescription rates across CCGs (NHS Clinical Commissioning Groups).  I am downloading the shapefile from http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/1bc1e6a77cdd4b3a9a0458b64af1ade4_1 which provides the CCG area boundaries.. However the initial problem I am encountering is to do with the reading of the shapefile. 
The following error is arising:

```
raise IOError('cannot locate %s.shp'%shapefile)
```

This is my code so far...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))

m = Basemap(resolution='c', # c, l, i, h, f or None
projection='merc',
lat_0=54.5, lon_0=-4.36,
llcrnrlon=-6., llcrnrlat= 49.5, urcrnrlon=2., urcrnrlat=55.2)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')
m.drawcoastlines()

m.readshapefile('/Volumes/Clinical_Commissioning_Groups_April_2016_Full_Extent_Boundaries_in_England', 'areas', drawbounds =True)
m.areas

df_poly = pd.DataFrame({'shapes': [Polygon(np.array(shape), True) for shape in    m.areas],'area': [area['ccg16cd'] for area in m.areas_info]})

rates=pd.read_csv('Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT/Basemap rates.csv', delimiter=",", usecols=[0,6])
rates.columns = ['ccg16cd','MEAN YEARLY PRESCRIPTION RATE']
frame = df_poly.merge(rates, on='ccg16cd', how='left')

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Oranges')
pc = PatchCollection(df_poly.shapes, zorder=2)
norm = Normalize()

pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(df_poly['count'].fillna(0).values)))
ax.add_collection(pc)

mapper = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

mapper.set_array(df_poly['count'])
plt.colorbar(mapper, shrink=0.4)

m
```

Would appreciate any pointers as to how I can achieve this choropleth map - starting with what is going wrong in reading the shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using geopandas to read in the shapefile:

import geopandas as gp

shape_file = gp.read_file('FileName.shp')

Also, check that the path to the shapefile is correct.

Comment: You'll need to install the package, using the following command: pip install geopandas